# UIImagePickerController photos shutter not opening

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimage, photos

i am developing iPad app which supports Landscape only

What i want to do is, i want to open photos library on button click.
Here is my code snippet,

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

when i wrote this it doesn't open photos library :(
I don't know where i am doing mistake

**Please help and thanks in adavance.**

Comment: add presentViewcontroller method

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate=self;
picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=8.0)
{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
}else{
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: It crashes and shows: `UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'`